# How do I search using Powershell for specifc word but exclude names with word embedded in name

Tags: powershell

I know this is probably simple or maybe not even possible, but my Powershell knowledge is novice and I've been tasked to create a search our file servers for filenames with "NDA" in them.  However, the script I created returns all filenames with NDA and NDA embedded (ie. it returns filenames like monday, calendar, fundamental, etc).  The persons wanting these results would like those embedded word results filtered out if possible.

```
Get-ChildItem -path u:\ -include *nda* -exclude *.tmp,*.lnk,*.xls,*.url,*.gif,*.bmp,*.msg,*.xlsx,*.kfg,*.sol,*.ics,*.srs,*.rtf,*.asd,*.dotx,*.xml -file -recurse
```

I've also tried this but it also returns all results.

```
Get-ChildItem u:\ -recurse -include *nda | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "nda"}
```

I've tried adding wildcards [ ] to try to eliminate the excess results but I'm not having luck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `-match` will find embedded nda also. Try `where BaseName -eq 'NDA'` instead. If you use `-like` you can add wildcards, i.e. `where BaseName -like "*-NDA"` if your wanted names include certain patterns. `BaseName` is the filename without extension.

Comment: Are all of the filenames you want returned formatted the same, such as "filename-NDA.ext"?

Comment: The team looking for the filenames are trying to do an audit.  So they are looking for anything with certain keywords within or embedded but I need to exclude false positives.  Makes it a lot more difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not shure if the exclude list will suffice I added an `or`-RegEx selecting nda at the begin/end/seperated with a non alphabet-char. The exlude list may be read in from a file.

```
$Exclude = @"
monday
calendar
fundamental
"@

Get-ChildItem -Path u:\ -recurse -include *nda* | 
  Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match "(^nda|[^a-z]nda[^a-z]|nda$)"}|
    Where-Object {$Exclude -notcontains $_.BaseName }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it :

```
Get-ChildItem "u:\" -recurse -file | Where BaseName -eq 'nda'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed